# Eclipse jUnit unit tests results not displaying

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

See example screenshots. I don't recall changing anything in any of my eclipse settings or anything. I am running eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) , Build id: 20190314-1200, jUnit version 4.12. I'm not sure what diagnostics or additional information to give to help debug this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The jUnit window has a toggle for `Show skipped Tests only` ,if  you have no tests it will show nothing, as per the question's image. (The image in this answer is not showing the results of skipped tests)

[image]